# Dynamic radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code to generate dynamic radio buttons according to an array.
This code generate number of radio buttons with its labels vertically.
When I try to get the checked radio button, I pass the name of the radio group to document.getElementsByName(). This return a node list item contain all radio buttons.

Console.log() shows node list's content as following:

```
       [item: function]: 
       0: input#r1
       1: input#r2
       2: input#r3
```

When I try to get the length of the node list, i got it 0, so that i can not access to the node list to get the checked radio button.

```
      ee.length /// 0
```

Could you please help me to find out why its length is 0?

// code

```
function addradiobutton( arr) {

        var foo = document.getElementById("mydiv");     
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            var label = document.createElement("label");
            var element = document.createElement("input");
            element.setAttribute("type", "radio");
            element.setAttribute("value", arr[i]);
            element.setAttribute("name", "gr");
            element.setAttribute("id", arr[i]);
            if (i==0)
              element.setAttribute("checked", true);
            label.appendChild(element);
            label.innerHTML += arr[i];
            label.innerHTML += '<br />';
            foo.appendChild(label);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please demonstrate your problem on a JSfiddle.

Comment: Can you show us the full code that performs the `getElementsByName()`

Comment: why are you adding the radio button inside the label ?

Comment: this is a demonstrate in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FPqV6/3/ .
i want to show a radio button next to the label name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the length of `ee` before you have added the radio buttons (which is why the length is 0).

Calling the alert after you have added the radio buttons gives the correct length:

```
addradiobutton(arr);
alert(ee.length);
console.log(ee.length);
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FPqV6/4/